# Is there a way to iterate through rows of a DataFrame and append some to a separate DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

What I want to do is something like:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.at['Column'] == some_value:
        some_other_df.append(row)
```

I can't seem to get this to work with the row object. It won't append like this, and it won't concatenate right with `pd.concat()`

Iterating through the rows creates a Series object, which is different from a DataFrame object, so it makes sense that it won't concatenate properly. Anyways, I'm looking for some method to be able to accomplish what the above pseudocode should.

Answer (score 1):

if you post the data as a code, it'll help in sharing the result from the solution.

this should help. try it out

```
some_other_df = df[df['Column'].eq(some_value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably filter or query instead of iterating.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, "Tom", 36, 3],
        [2, "Bob", 30, 2]
    ],
    columns=["ID", "Name", "Age", "Children"]
)
print(f"{df1}\n")

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [3, "Joe", 23, 1],
        [4, "Mike", 27, 4]
    ],
    columns=["ID", "Name", "Age", "Children"]
)
print(f"{df2}\n")

filtered_df = df1.query("Name == 'Tom'")
final_df = pd.concat([df2, filtered_df], ignore_index=True)
print(final_df)
```

Comment: Agree. Iterating through all the rows will be slower than filter + concat.